# Google-Images API Integration with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a `Discord.js` bot that sends google images based on user arguments. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you getting any errors we could use to help diagnose the problem?

Comment: According to the [`google-images` npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-images), you need an API key and CSE ID

Comment: The api and cse key is there i just removed it when sending the snippet for privacy reasons

Comment: Ah, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```js
return client2.search(`${term}`)
  .then(images => message.channel.send({ files: [images[0].url] });
```

---

First of all, `client.search()` returns an `array` of `objects`, so you won't be able to send it as it is. Looking at the `google-images` docs, a sample array would look like this:

```js
[
 {
  url: 'http://steveangello.com/boss.jpg',
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  width: 1024,
  height: 768,
  size: 102451,
  thumbnail: {
   url: 'http://steveangello.com/thumbnail.jpg',
   width: 512,
   height: 512,
  },
 },
];
```

Following that structure, `images[0].url` is the `URL` of the first image found.